# How exactly hash comparison will happen in Digitally Signed PDF ?? Mainly in multiple Signings

Tags: pdf, adobe, pdfbox

When PDF is digitally signed multiple times each time hash will change, But all the signatures are valid. 
How this hash comparison will happen in PDF ??

Comment: https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/etk_deprecated/tools/DigSig/Acrobat_DigitalSignatures_in_PDF.pdf look for "byterange" this will be a good start (on a complex topic)

Comment: Also read [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/35131/16096) for some backgrounds and references.

Comment: Yeah I remember that one, but didn't "find" it this time. @Shashichandra I recommend that you study that answer first, delete your question, and then create a new question with whatever you wish to be helped.

Comment: Ok. Thanks  Tilman Hausherr and mkl